A efficient algorithm for the householder transformation of a hermitian matrix
I've implemented a version of the householder transformation in Burden's numerical analysis which can also be found on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation#Tridiagonalization
It works very well for real symmetric matrices, but unfortunately I haven't been able to convert it to a algorithm that also works for hermitian matrices which I guess should be possible, even if the geometric interpretation of the Householder transformation is difficult in this case.
Simply changing $v^T$ to $v^*$ has unfortunately not worked.
Edit: As this question hasn't gained much traction and I want to set a bounty, I'm going to elabore my problem: I have a (small) complex valued hermitian matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and I'm trying to find an efficient algorithm that gets this matrix into a real symmetric tridiagonal matrix. I've read this is possible but have unfortunately just found algorithms that deal with the real valued case, while the authors write that the same algorithms should be changed appropriately for hermitian matrices.
So what changes need to be made explicitly? Just changing the obvious has not worked for me.

First, we can make use of a version of the Householder reflection for complex vectors.  Given a complex vector $x$, with
$x_{1}=e^{i \theta} | x_{1} |$,
let
$u=\frac{x+e^{i\theta} \| x \| e_{1}}{\| x+e^{i\theta} \| x \| e_{1}\|}$
and
$H=-e^{-i\theta}(I-2uu^{H})$.
You can show with a bit of simplification that $Hx=\| x \|e_{1}$ and that $H$ is a unitary matrix.  Thus $H$ acts as a Householder transformation.
Since I haven't been able to find a good reference for this calculation, here's a derivation.
First, we show that $Hx=\| x \| e_{1}$.
Let $v=x+e^{i \theta} \| x \| e_{1}$ and $u=v/\| v \|$.
Then
$Hx=-e^{-i \theta} \left( I-2 \frac{vv^{H}}{v^{H}v} \right) \left( v-e^{i\theta} \| x \| e_{1} \right).$
$Hx=-e^{-i \theta}v + \| x \| e_{1} + 
2e^{-i\theta}\frac{vv^{H}}{v^{H}v}v -
2e^{-i \theta} \frac{vv^{H}}{v^{H}v} e^{i\theta} \| x \| e_{1}.$
$Hx=\| x \| e_{1} +
e^{-i\theta}v -2e^{-i \theta} \frac{v^{H}e_{1}}{v^{H}v} e^{i\theta} \| x \| v.$
$Hx=\| x \| e_{1} +
e^{-i\theta}v -2e^{-i \theta} \frac{v^{H}e_{1}}{v^{H}v} e^{i\theta} \| x \| v.$
$Hx=\| x \| e_{1} +
e^{-i\theta}v -2e^{-i \theta} \frac{x_{1}^{H}+e^{-i \theta} \| x \|}{2(\| x \|^{2} + |x_{1} | \| x \|)} e^{i\theta} \| x \| v.$
$Hx=\| x \| e_{1} +
e^{-i\theta}v -2e^{-i \theta} \frac{| x_{1} | \| x \|+ \| x \|^{2}}{2(\| x \|^{2} + |x_{1} | \| x \|)} v.$
$Hx=\| x \| e_{1}+ e^{-i \theta}v - e^{-i \theta}v$.
$Hx=\| x \| e_{1}$.
To show that $H$ is unitary,
$HH^{H}=(I-2uu^{H})(I-2uu^{H}).$
$HH^{H}=I-2uu^{H}-2uu^{H}+4uu^{H}uu^{H}.$
$HH^{H}=I-4uu^{H}+4uu^{H}=I.$
Here's a MATLAB function to compute $H$.
%
% H=complexhr(x)
%
% Computes the complex Householder matrix associated with a vector $x$.
% This results in $Hx=\| x \| e_{1}$.
%
function H=complexhr(x)
%
% Get the size of x
%
n=length(x);
%
% Compute the required phase shift.
%
theta=angle(x(1));
phase=exp(i*theta);
%
% e1 appears in the formula.
%
e1=zeros(n,1);
e1(1)=1;
%
% Compute u.
%
u=(x+phase*norm(x)*e1);
u=u/norm(u);
%
% Compute the transformation matrix H.
%
H=-exp(-i*theta)*(eye(n)-2*u*u');

Next, use this $H$ in the tridiagonalization of $A$.
%
% [T,Q]=tridiag(A)
%
% Given a complex hermitian matrix A, produce a unitarily
% equivalent matrix T and a unitary matrix Q with Q*A*Q'=T.
%
function [T,Q]=tridiag(A)
%
% Get the matrix size.
%
n=size(A,1);
%
% Start with T=A and Q=I.
%
T=A;
Q=eye(n);
%
% Loop over the columns of A and apply Householder 
% reflections.
%
for j=1:n-2
  %
  % Compute the Householder reflection for this column/row.
  %
  temp=T(j+1:end,j);
  H=complexhr(temp);
  Qtemp=[eye(j) zeros(j,n-j); zeros(n-j,j) H];
  %
  % Update T.
  %
  T=Qtemp*T*Qtemp'
  %
  % Update Q.
  %
  Q=Qtemp*Q;
end

In practice, you'd probably want to make use of a LAPACK routine for tridiagonal reduction.

Thanks for the answer. Do you know of any literature where the complex Householder reduction is discussed in detail regarding runtime and it's explicitly shown that H has the desired properties (being unitary and $Hx = \vert \vert x \vert \vert e_1$)?

I couldn't find a reference that had the derivation of this formula, so I went ahead and put the work into the answer.  The computational complexity of the tridiagonalization is $O(n^{3})$, just as in the real case.
